# Nokia s40 testing GPS or location based service

Tags: java, eclipse, geolocation, nokia, nokia-s40

I'm new to developing S40 Nokia applications using Java.  I need to send to the emulator a latitude and longitude like the android emulator, you can update the location by passing latitude and longitude from the emulator.

I'm using eclipse, can any body help please?

Comment: *"can any body help please?"*  Help with what exactly?  What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Nokia SDK for Java 1.0 can play co-ordinates from a saved file to any midlet. When this file exists, any MIDlet which uses JSR 179 API to get current location in the emulator, will receive these saved co-ordinates at regular intervals.

Emulator also includes a *Route Editor*. You can launch it from the emulator's *Tools > Route Editor* menu. Route Editor helps you create a file with co-ordinates, this file is saved by the Route Editor to a location under the current emulator instance's directory. You can check out the details from the emulator documentation.

Also, if you are using SDK 2.0, you can pinpoint your current location, as well as draw route from the "Tools" >> "Location Simulation" options.